# The unit group of $\mathbb{Z}\big[w\big]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, solution-verification

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}\big[ w \big]=\{a+bw | a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and where $w=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. Which elements of $\mathbb{Z}\big[ w \big]$ are invertible?

I want to calculate $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+bw$ is a unit. Therefore for $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$

$$(a+bw)(c+dw)=1 \Rightarrow |(a+bw)|^2|(c+dw)|^2=1 \Rightarrow ((2a-b)^2+3b^2)((2c-d)^2+3d^2)=16$$

and by dividing into cases I got that $\{\pm 1,\pm w,\pm(1+w)\}$ is the set of all invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}\big[ w \big]$.

My questions is how could I find the units of the ring without using the complex modulus?

Comment: Hint:$1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.

Comment: $a+bw$ is invertible iff its field norm is invertible, ie. $|a+bw|^2 = 1$.

Comment: The norm is $N(a + b \omega) = (a + b \omega)(a + b \omega^2) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $N(zw) = N(z) N(w)$ and that $z$ is invertible iff $N(z) = \pm 1$. This is the very standard argument. You don't technically need to know anything about complex numbers to write $N$ down, and the same argument generalizes to e.g. real quadratic fields where $N$ is not the complex modulus.